# Like Box Code not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

Page: http://www.facebook.com/Travel.by.Design

Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/travel.by.design" width="292" show_faces="true" stream="true" header="false" css="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/fbstyle.css?1"></fb:like-box>
```

website: http://waldhaus.com

On same website we have more Like Boxes installed and they all work with same code ( just different URL's). So I assume it must have to do with specific URL

other code, same website works:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/farmeadow" width="292" show_faces="true" stream="true" header="false" css="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/fbstyle.css?1"></fb:like-box>
```

Comment: Can you provide more information please? What is not working with the code?

Comment: We have several Like box widgets on the page, they all work, just the one with the code above doesn't.(Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.)@lix

Answer (score 0):

You have 8 different `div` elements with an `id` of `fb-root`.
The browser can not decide which one to use.  You only need one of `div` with `fb-root` on your page.  
You should **always** have unique values in the `id` property of **any** element.
As you have stated from the comments above, the error you are getting is -

> Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct
>   href was passed in.

The browser doesn't know what `fb-root` element to latch onto.