# Like box for pages - listing of news / Show Posts - not working

Tags: facebook, widget, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I am managing one of the Facebook brand pages and now need to add a widget to my site.
But i can get the listing of news using - like box for pages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

If i choose "Show Friends' Faces" - it works ok ,but for "Show Posts" - nothing.
Page has 200+ people and regular news updates, no complaints or something.

But the last one was in 4th of september - may it be the reason?

Or maybe some privacy settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I saw there are several questions like mine here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393179/like-box-does-not-display-posts
- [Like Box Code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927461/like-box-code-not-working)

Finally I moved other way - exporting RSS feed via some JS-plugin and inserting it on a page.

Every Facebook page has RSS by url like this:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=YOUR_PAGE_ID
than you can use jQuery plugin, for example this one - [FeedEk jQuery RSS/ATOM Feed Plugin](http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html)